# video page in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, video

I need this:

[image]

will a link to the video file will get me to there when clicked or I need to link to a page and put some code on it?

thanks!

-EDIT-

i tried to link to http://www.lich-t.info/wp-content/themes/suedlich-t/portfolio/2011/Friendscout24_Kissing_Teddy_1.mp4

and this was the result:

[image]

what am I missing??

Comment: Just try it out. My guess is it should just work. Just let us know if it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can simply link to an MP4 video, and iOS will automatically play it in its QuickTime Player.

No need for any specific HTML page.

**Note:** Ascertain that your video is encoded properly http://www.google.com/search?q=site:apple.com+encode+video+iPhone

Comment: Like I said: you can simply link to the video directly. No HTML involved. Your video is probably not encoded correctly.